# Filter Where clause in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have the following postgres table.

```
users = Table('users', metadata,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
Column('name', String),
Column('fullname', String),
)
```

Suppose I want to get counts like so:

```
select count(*) filter (where name = 'name') as nnames, 
count(*) as n 
from users
```

Is it possible to do something similar to the above query with the sqlalchemy ORM using a query? I have not seen anything in the documentation. My current solution involves `subquery` and `select`.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.filter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

Table.query.values(func.count().filter(Table.name == "name"), func.count())
```

I did so in flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: Since version 1.4 `.where()` is a synonym of `.filter()` as explained in [sqlalchemy.orm.Query.where](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.where).